# Google Maps Fusion Table API SQL "LIKE" command not working

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Google Maps API to pull data from a Fusion Table based on user input. I trying to use the "LIKE" command to create  a more robust search feature, however anything other than simple where queries (like where x=y or x>y) seems to return every entry or no entry at all from the fusion table.

main.js

```
function updateMap(layer, tableID) {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var newLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'FULL_ADDRESS',
            from: tableID,
            where: "FULL_ADDRESS LIKE  \'%" + input + "%\' "
        }
    });
    console.log(newLayer);
    layer.setMap(null);//deletes old layer
    newLayer.setMap(map);//sets map to new layer
    LAYER = newLayer;// sets global layer to new layer

}
```

according to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) and [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference) this should work fine.

index.html

```
<input id="input" class="controls floating-label" type="text" placeholder="Search by Address or Zip Code">
```

fusion table entry

> 000000000000000000| Taylor Road , Birmingham, AL, 36117| 0 |$0.00 $6,800.00 |$0.00 |$0.00 |$1,360.00

2nd field is FULL_ADDRESS

[live site](http://absoluteinfinityllc.com:9000/)
My goal is to use the user input to try to partially match a addresses however, it is not working correctly. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you see `ILIKE` in the documentation?  I only see `LIKE` and `MATCHES`.

Comment: I made an assumption that It was just undocumented updating the question would "IGNORING CASE" instead?.

Comment: If it isn't listed, I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work.  Does `LIKE` and/or `MATCHES` work?

Comment: like didn't work but matches did !!!!! thanks

Comment: There is no ILIKE in Fusion Tables SQL. LIKE and MATCHES are synonyms. See the SQL reference: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` doesn't appear to work so use `MATCHES` instead